# Perl: Sorting multilevel hash with values from inner hash when using Data::Dumper

Tags: perl, data-dumper

I want to print multilevel hash using `Data::Dumper`. I want output to be sorted based on values from inner hash. I tried following few examples to redefine `Data::Dumper::Sortkeys` to sort on values for keys `index` but it doesn't seem to work. Here is what I tried:

```
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;
use Data::Dumper;
use Storable qw(dclone);
use File::Basename;
use Perl::Tidy;


my $hash = {
    key1 => {
        index => 100,
    },
    key3 => {
        index => 110,
    },
    key2 => {
        index => 99,
    },
    key5 => {
        index => 81,
    },
    key4 => {
        index => 107,
    },

};

#$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys =
    sub {
        [sort {$b->{'index'} <=> $a->{'index'}} keys %{$_[0]}];
        };



print Dumper $hash;
```

I expect:

```
$VAR1 = {
    key5 => {
        index => 81,
    },
    key2 => {
        index => 99,
    },
    key1 => {
        index => 100,
    },
    key4 => {
        index => 107,
    },
    key3 => {
        index => 110,
    },

};
```

Here is what I get:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'key5' => {
                      'index' => 81
                    },
          'key4' => {
                      'index' => 107
                    },
          'key3' => {
                      'index' => 110
                    },
          'key2' => {
                      'index' => 99
                    },
          'key1' => {
                      'index' => 100
                    }
        };
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The [perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc) (Perl Data Structures Cookbook) has lots of interesting examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables `$a` and `$b` hold the keys, so you have to use the hashref in your sortkeys sub to access the actual elements.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;


my $hash = {
    key1 => {
        index => 100,
    },
    key3 => {
        index => 110,
    },
    key2 => {
        index => 99,
    },
    key5 => {
        index => 81,
    },
    key4 => {
        index => 107,
    },

};

#$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys =
    sub {
        my $h = $_[0];
        my @keys =  keys %{$h};
        [ sort {$h->{$a}{index} <=> $h->{$b}{index}} @keys]
        };

print Dumper $hash;
```